# Evolution's calendar desktop notifications fail appearing

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, notifications, calendar, evolution

I installed Evolution recently, for its Google Calendar integration, but it produces strange behaviors.

In certain "test cases", the program was able to execute a desktop notification about upcoming events - of course, when I added notification option to the event.

However, it very often happens that even if I start Evolution and join the internet thereafter (it's not always automatic because I don't always have access to Wi-Fi), it fails showing up notifications. Said events have notifications set up, because they appear on my phone, but fail to appear on my desktop, where it's supposed to be done by Evolution.

Even worse, I realized that I have to close a process called `/usr/lib/evolutin-data-server/evolution-calendar-factory` in `htop` and **then** restart Evolution to fix this error. In this case, **all** the missed desktop notification pop up on my screen, as Evolution starts.

It's a very strange condition and also very inconvenient for me. How can I fix it? Is it related to internet connection issues?